# Testem / Jasmine: How to change jasmine version in grunt-contrib-testem

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, testem

Is it possible to change the Jasmine version in grunt-contrib-testem? I would like to use the latest 2.3 version of Jasmine.  This latest version has methods like beforeAll and afterAll.

When I tried to set framework to jasmine2.3 in Grunt configuration, it fails.

I have given below the configuration options for testem in Grunt.

```
testem: {
      unit: {
        options: {
          framework: 'jasmine2',
          launch_in_dev: ['PhantomJS'],
```